# PDO Mysql Not returning results properly

Tags: php, mysql

I'm stuck with this really weird situation.

I have a Mysql server and an app server. App server connects to Mysql via private network and I grant *.* privileges to both users.

This is my code from app server:

```
$db2 = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $host . ';dbname=' .$database. ';charset=utf8mb4', $userid, $db_password);
$db2->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$db2->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

$somequery = $db2->query('SELECT mail,message_id from mc_mails');
$somequery->execute();

$somedata = $somequery->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

pretty_print($somedata); //my own <pre>print_r()</pre> function

var_dump($somedata); //shows raw dump

//so below I try to do again in a try loop to get Exception, and there's no exception.
try {
    $somequery->execute();

    while ($row = $somequery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ORI_NEXT)) {
        pretty_print($row);
    }
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

The above yields the following results:

This is from pretty_print():

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [mail] => 20
            [message_id] => <2061A721-82BE-48EC-BA44-D2CD6D6DAC00@gmail.com>
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [mail] => 21
            [message_id] => <8064AD4C-7C30-499B-8D83-E7DBABADCF36@gmail.com>
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [mail] => 22
            [message_id] => 
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [mail] => 23
            [message_id] => 
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [mail] => 24
            [message_id] => 
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [mail] => 25
            [message_id] => 
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [mail] => 26
            [message_id] => 
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [mail] => 27
            [message_id] => <850E2143-F797-4B6B-8F29-1004EEBCC0D2@gmail.com>
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [mail] => 28
            [message_id] => 
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [mail] => 29
            [message_id] => 
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [mail] => 30
            [message_id] => <59DED427-255B-45EB-AC10-172FD49D529D@gmail.com>
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [mail] => 31
            [message_id] => <50360840-52AD-44FE-9257-B51610F36171@gmail.com>
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [mail] => 34
            [message_id] => 
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [mail] => 35
            [message_id] => 
        )

)
```

This is from var_dump():

```
array(14) { [0]=> array(2) { ["mail"]=> int(20) ["message_id"]=> string(48) "<2061A721-82BE-48EC-BA44-D2CD6D6DAC00@gmail.com>" } [1]=> array(2) { ["mail"]=> int(21) ["message_id"]=> string(48) "<8064AD4C-7C30-499B-8D83-E7DBABADCF36@gmail.com>" } [2]=> array(2) { ["mail"]=> int(22) ["message_id"]=> string(48) "" } [3]=> array(2) { ["mail"]=> int(23) ["message_id"]=> string(48) "" } [4]=> array(2) { ["mail"]=> int(24) ["message_id"]=> string(48) "" } [5]=> array(2) { ["mail"]=> int(25) ["message_id"]=> string(48) "" } [6]=> array(2) { ["mail"]=> int(26) ["message_id"]=> string(48) "" } [7]=> array(2) { ["mail"]=> int(27) ["message_id"]=> string(48) "<850E2143-F797-4B6B-8F29-1004EEBCC0D2@gmail.com>" } [8]=> array(2) { ["mail"]=> int(28) ["message_id"]=> string(48) "" } [9]=> array(2) { ["mail"]=> int(29) ["message_id"]=> string(48) "" } [10]=> array(2) { ["mail"]=> int(30) ["message_id"]=> string(48) "<59DED427-255B-45EB-AC10-172FD49D529D@gmail.com>" } [11]=> array(2) { ["mail"]=> int(31) ["message_id"]=> string(48) "<50360840-52AD-44FE-9257-B51610F36171@gmail.com>" } [12]=> array(2) { ["mail"]=> int(34) ["message_id"]=> string(48) "" } [13]=> array(2) { ["mail"]=> int(35) ["message_id"]=> string(48) "" } }
```

This is from fetch loop:

```
Array
(
    [mail] => 20
    [0] => 20
    [message_id] => <2061A721-82BE-48EC-BA44-D2CD6D6DAC00@gmail.com>
    [1] => <2061A721-82BE-48EC-BA44-D2CD6D6DAC00@gmail.com>
)
Array
(
    [mail] => 21
    [0] => 21
    [message_id] => <8064AD4C-7C30-499B-8D83-E7DBABADCF36@gmail.com>
    [1] => <8064AD4C-7C30-499B-8D83-E7DBABADCF36@gmail.com>
)
Array
(
    [mail] => 22
    [0] => 22
    [message_id] => 
    [1] => 
)
Array
(
    [mail] => 23
    [0] => 23
    [message_id] => 
    [1] => 
)
Array
(
    [mail] => 24
    [0] => 24
    [message_id] => 
    [1] => 
)
Array
(
    [mail] => 25
    [0] => 25
    [message_id] => 
    [1] => 
)
Array
(
    [mail] => 26
    [0] => 26
    [message_id] => 
    [1] => 
)
Array
(
    [mail] => 27
    [0] => 27
    [message_id] => <850E2143-F797-4B6B-8F29-1004EEBCC0D2@gmail.com>
    [1] => <850E2143-F797-4B6B-8F29-1004EEBCC0D2@gmail.com>
)
Array
(
    [mail] => 28
    [0] => 28
    [message_id] => 
    [1] => 
)
Array
(
    [mail] => 29
    [0] => 29
    [message_id] => 
    [1] => 
)
Array
(
    [mail] => 30
    [0] => 30
    [message_id] => <59DED427-255B-45EB-AC10-172FD49D529D@gmail.com>
    [1] => <59DED427-255B-45EB-AC10-172FD49D529D@gmail.com>
)
Array
(
    [mail] => 31
    [0] => 31
    [message_id] => <50360840-52AD-44FE-9257-B51610F36171@gmail.com>
    [1] => <50360840-52AD-44FE-9257-B51610F36171@gmail.com>
)
Array
(
    [mail] => 34
    [0] => 34
    [message_id] => 
    [1] => 
)
Array
(
    [mail] => 35
    [0] => 35
    [message_id] => 
    [1] => 
)
```

I have no idea why some of the arrays are empty. Notice the `var_dump` results show there's string of 48 but it's still empty.

The loop also shows something in the array but it never gets printed. However, the exact same query I used directly in ssh gives me the following. All the fields are set.

[image]

I'm not sure whether that's the problem but my `message_id` is `varchar(1000)` - yes it's very big, but I'm just starting to learn about email headers and I read rfc is about 1000 chars for message-id though I doubt it ever go past that.

Need help please. I'm stuck.

EDIT: This happens in many fields too, I'm just choosing one field for clarity.

Comment: What's the point in PDO::FETCH_ORI_NEXT?

Comment: Can you show create statement for your table

Comment: I note that in each case where the data is not printed the first character is alphabetic, the rows where it is printed the following character is numeric.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're dumping into a browser, and those message IDs have `<>`, which means they're being rendered as unknown/illegal html tags. Do a view-source of the page, and you'll see they're there

I'm guessing the first two that DO show up were encoded with `&lt;...&gt;`, so they show as text, not rendered as html.

Comment: I think tag can not start with number, that is why it shows it properly.

Comment: @E_p: maybe, but there's nothing in the html5 spec that says they can't. it just says `[0-9a-zA-Z]`: [tag name](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#tag-name)

Comment: THANK U! I've been stucked with this so long i never thought it will be because of html! I think i have to find other way to display this then. thank u!

Comment: basically: never ever trust what your browser shows. it's job is to TRANSLATE text into a viewable form. it can't read your mind and know you want debug output - it's all the same html to the browser. always check view-source